# Creating Data Table from object array

Tags: c#-4.0, xls, import-from-excel

I am not sure if I am going about this the correct way but I have a c# method which loads an excel sheet into a 2 dimentional object array. In this array item 1,1 - 1,16 contain headers, then 2-1 - 2-16 contain data that match up with those headers as do x-1 - x-16 from there on in. I would like to turn this array into a data table so ultimately I can have it in a format I will then import into an access or SQL server db depending on a clients needs. I have tried using the following code to no avail, but I have a feeling I am way off. Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

```
private void ProcessObjects(object[,] valueArray)
{
    DataTable holdingTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow holdingRow;
    holdingTable.BeginLoadData();
    foreach(int row in valueArray)
    {
        holdingRow = holdingTable.LoadDataRow(valueArray[row], true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're using a repository pattern (like subsonic or EF) or using LinqToSql?

You could do this (LinqToSql for simplicity):

```
List<SomeType> myList = valueArray.ToList().Skip([your header rows]).ConvertAll(f => Property1 = f[0] [the rest of your convert statement])
DataContext dc = new DataContext();

dc.SomeType.InsertAllOnSubmit(myList);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Im sorry you have to bear with me, I am not familliar with LINQ to SQL at all. If I am understanding that code it is creating a list valueArray instead of an object array as I have created? Now in the skip section I am making the assumption [your header rows] would be replaced with the range of cells (i.e. .Skip("A1:D16")) but what would be the value of the rest of your convert statement? right now i decided to go another way, but I am very interested in learning this LINQ approach. I have attached the new code in a reply, please let me know your thoughts.